# kafka partition leader HW and ISR failover

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, failover

I read from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Replication

> So, for each committed message, we guarantee that the message is stored in >multiple replicas in memory. However, there is no guarantee that any >replica has persisted the commit message to disks though

It makes sense to only store the message in follower's memory after ack in order to achieve low latency. But the article doesn't tell whether the leader persists the message. What if the leader crashes?

Answer (score 0):

After pondering on the topic, I figured out that the leader also doesn't need to persist the message. The committed message guarantee is provided by the assumption that at least one replica in ISR will survive. A new leader will be elected with committed message available in case of the original leader crash